# How to include chromedriver in requirements.txt

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

How do I include chromedriver inside the requirements.txt?

Tried adding the below line but doesn't work

```
chromedriver==2.4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the package name is not good.

Try `chromedriver_installer==2.4.2`

as stated in chromedriver [docs](https://pypi.org/project/chromedriver_installer/)